# Atomics and Multi-Threading in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

So I'm messing around with *atomic* and *thread* and made this program that reads and writes to an array based on whether an atomic is engaged.

When it compiles, however, the outputs seems to vary.

EDIT: by vary, I mean "k" and "out" are not identical on compilation.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

std::atomic<bool> busy (false);
std::atomic_int out (0);

void do_thing(std::vector<int>* inputs) {
    while(!busy) {
        std::this_thread::yield();
    }

    int next = inputs->back();
    inputs->pop_back();
    
    out.store(out.load(std::memory_order_relaxed) + next, std::memory_order_relaxed);
}

int main(void) {

    std::vector<int> inputs;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) inputs.push_back(rand() % 10);

    // base
    int k = 0;
    for(auto& el : inputs) k += el;
    std::cout << k << std::endl;

    // threaded
    try {
        std::vector<std::thread> threads;
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) threads.push_back(std::thread(do_thing, &inputs));
        busy = true;
        for (auto& th : threads) th.join();
        std::cout << out.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Could anyone point out what is happening?

I have a feeling this could be done better with a mutex, but was curious about why it happens anyhow.

Cheers,

K

Comment: You should tell us what you're expecting to do. Also, the output of your program is going to change every time you run it simply because you're using random data every time you run it.

Comment: What's to explain? You have a multitude of data races accessing `inputs`.  Undefined behavior results.

Comment: Your threads are all modifying a vector without synchronization.

Comment: In a multithreaded program, the behavior will always vary, unless you've applied synchronization mechanisms to strictly govern the behavior of the threads.  The variation comes from the fact that the each thread is scheduled based on system timers, scheduler heuristics, system load, etc, and those things are always different from one execution to the next.

Comment: ok, so atomic cannot be used as synchronization tools I guess!

Comment: It can, sort of.  But not the way you're doing it.  Use `std::mutex` to control access to your vector.  `std::atomic` is most appropriate if you want to atomically update some value such as a counter (_e.g._ reference-counting for resource control).

Comment: Just because `out` is an "atomic" variable, that does not make `out.store(out.load(...) + next,...);` an atomic operation. Two (or more) different threads both could call `out.load(...)` and get the same value, then each could add its own `next` to that value, and store it back. One of the `next`s just got lost--overwritten by the action of the other thread. The individual `out.xxxxx()` calls were atomic, but the _sequence_ is not.

Comment: I don't think using `memory_order_relaxed` ordering in `do_thing` is a good choice here as other threads may not see the newest updates to the variable. Start by using `memory_order_seq_cst` and get your algorithm working before tinkering with weaker orderings.